# Conditional https redirect to http depending on URL? (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redirect, https

Right now I redirect 100% of the time if someone does https://mysite.com

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
   ServerName mysite.com
   ServerAlias www.mysite.com

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=permanent]
<VirtualHost>
```

However, now I want to conditionally redirect. If a user goes to https://mysite.com/abc/, then I want to use https; otherwise redirect.

How do I do this? I tried reading the docs, but just couldn't find what I needed.

I am using Apache on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a *RewriteCond* (Rewrite Condition) before the *RewriteRule*.
I would try writing something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(abc).*$ [NC]
```

Here is some additional reading if this doesn't help:
- http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/apache-rewrite.html
- http://www.sitepoint.com/article/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: Thus, what you offered seems to make sense on the surface, but I get this when reloading Apache RewriteCond: bad argument line '!^%{HTTP_HOST}/abc'.

I am trying to read the links you sent me to see if there is any more hints.

Comment: It is probably just my syntax that is wrong. I don't have a machine to test it on myself at the moment. Please post the correct syntax when you figure it out. Good luck! :)

Comment: Well, I tried different syntax that seemed to work --- RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(abc).*$ [NC] --- Thanks for your help and trying to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that I could help. I edited the syntax of my answer to your corrected version.

Comment: This answer will also use HTTPS for things like `https://mysite.com/foo/test/abcdef`, which I think is not what you (Joel) wanted. And anyway, it's way overkill to add on a `RewriteCond` just to test against the request URI. (Not downvoting, though... it does technically work)

Comment: David: Thank you for providing me with some additional insight into this subject! Your solution looks much cleaner and correct than mine. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2):

I'll reproduce the answer I gave you on the Slicehost forums:

```
RewriteRule !^/abc/ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=permanent]
```

(edited)

Comment: I had to remove the space between the `!` and the `^` to get this to work for me, otherwise I was getting "bad flag delimiters".

Answer (score 0):

There are examples for apache:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost

> You can alternatively accomplish this using the  directive: (2.4
>   and later)
>
> Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"  Or, for example, to redirect a portion of your site to HTTPS, you might do the following:
>
> Redirect "/admin/" "https://www.example.com/admin/"